# Running Silent Installers as Jobs with Powershell

Tags: powershell

This works just fine:

> Start-Job -Name notepadpp -ScriptBlock {
>   c:\directory\install\npp.6.5.1.Installer.exe /S }

This however does NOT:

> Start-Job -Name notepadpp -ScriptBlock { &
>   "$using:pwd\install\npp.6.5.1.Installer.exe /S" }

What am I missing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Start-Job -Name notepadpp -ScriptBlock { & "$($using:pwd)\install\npp.6.5.1.Installer.exe" /S }
```

Answer (score 1):

It should probably be

```
Start-Job -Name notepadpp -ScriptBlock { & "$($using:pwd)\install\npp.6.5.1.Installer.exe /S" }
```

Comment: Sorry for the delay but it's better now than ever, right? :)

You was very close.

Start-Job -Name notepadpp -ScriptBlock { & "$($using:pwd)\install\npp.6.5.1.Installer.exe" /S }

is the right way to do it.